# Cannot read property 'play' of undefined JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Пытаюсь сделай простейший драм. Хотел, чтобы при клики на класс `button` запускался звук.

В чем ошибка)?

Код:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.button').mousedown(function(event) {
  var audio = $('audio').autoplay;
  audio.play();
});
$('.button').mouseup(function(event) {
  var audio = $('audio').autoplay;
  audio.stop();
    });
})
```

```css
.piano{
display: flex;
width:100%;
}

.button{
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background-color: red;
margin-left: 20px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="piano">
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>

</div>

<audio src="Sound_18050.mp3"></audio>
```

Ошибка при нажатии на `.button`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно понимать, что этим кодом: `$('audio')`, вы создаёте jquery объект. И у него нет свойства "autoplay". Поэтому пытаясь вызвать метод `.play()` на несуществующем свойстве вы получаете эту ошибку.
То, что вы пытаетесь сделать, скорее всего, нуждается в таком коде:

```
$(function(){
$('.button').mousedown(function(event) {
    $('audio')[0].play();
});
$('.button').mouseup(function(event) {
    $('audio')[0].stop();
});
})
```

Comment: А что означает [0]?

Comment: @DimaLol jquery объект является массивом с js dom нодами (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node), и этим я беру первую ноду из массива, которая обладает методами .play() и .stop()

Comment: @DimaLol только судя по другим ответам метода .stop() не существует, используйте .pause()

Comment: т.е если я создам ещё одну переменную(например var kek = $('.piano')) к ней я буду обращаться [1]?

Comment: @DimaLol возможно, если в DOM будет два элемента с классом .piano, то выбрать второй из них можно так. Первый будет выбираться индексом 0, ибо $('.piano') - это просто массив элементов, попавших под указанный селектор, и получать к ним доступ можно соответствующе.

Comment: Разобрался). Спасибо всем, кто помог!

Comment: @DimaLol стрелка вверх на ответе - лучшее спасибо) И конкретно от меня - пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

1. Использовать обращение - `audio[0]` (получает первый элемент)
2. Метода stop() нет, стоит заменить на `audio[0].pause(); audio[0].currentTime = 0;`

```js
$('.button').mousedown(function() {
    var audio = $('audio');
    audio[0].play();
});

$('.button').mouseup(function() {
    var audio = $('audio');
    
  audio[0].pause();
  audio[0].currentTime = 0;  
});
```

```css
.piano{
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
}

.button{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 20px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

  
<div class="piano">
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>

</div>

<audio id="myAudio" src="https://stopmusic.net/_ld/57/5776_Axwell_Ingrosso.mp3"></audio>
```

[Рабочий пример на jsbin](https://jsbin.com/liticaw/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

> Хотел, чтобы при клики на класс button запускался звук. В чем ошибка)?

Надо обращатся, к первму элементу аудио.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var audio = $('audio')
  $('.play').click(function(event) {
    audio[0].play();
  });
  $('.pause').click(function() { // Pause
    audio[0].pause();
  })
  $('.stop').click(function(event) {// Stop
    audio[0].pause();
    audio[0].currentTime = 0;
  });

})
```

```css
.piano {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.button i {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="piano">
  <div class="button play" title='play'>
    <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="button pause" title='pause'>
  <i class="fas fa-pause"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="button stop" title='stop'>
  <i class="fas fa-stop"></i>
  </div>

</div>

<audio src="https://archive.org/download/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: Разобрался). Спасибо всем, кто помог!